# Immer - Mutate Newly Created Nested Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I'm using immer (via `createSlice` in `redux-toolkit`) to manage state in a redux application. I've written a reducer that takes a payload of music tracks and adds them to the users library. In part, this reducer must also create artist entries for each of the tracks.

```
createTracks(draft, action: PayloadAction<{ tracks: Array<ITrack> | ITrack; }>) {
  ...
  tracks.forEach((track, index) => {
    ...
      // Check to see if artist exists, if not create, if so, add this track
      let artist = draft.artists[artistId];
      if (!artist) {
        console.log("creating artist", track.artist);
        draft.artists[artistId] = produce({
          name: track.artist,
          albums: [],
          id: artistId,
          tracks: [track.id]
        }, (artistDraft): IArtist => {
          console.log("producing the artist");
          return artistDraft;
        });
      } else {
        console.log("updating artist");
        draft.artists[artistId].tracks.push(track.id);
      }
```

This works fine for the first tracks from each artist. However, when immer creates each new artist object and adds it to the state, it makes the track array for each object not extensible.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible
```

is thrown from

```
draft.artists[artistId].tracks.push(track.id);
```

I've presumed that this is because I'm either not creating the the nested artist draft correctly or redux doesn't support this behavior. That's why I shifted from using a pure object to a nested immer draft - but this didn't seem to work.

I have also tried...

```
draft.artists[artistId].tracks = [...draft.artists[artistId].tracks, track.id];
```

... but in this case, the `tracks` property is read only.

How can I implement this without the error?

Comment: May I ask why you are using produce within an already immerized reducer at all? Just creating the new object should have the same effect, unless you want to modify some properties that came in from an external data source from the action.

Comment: It was a bad effort at debugging the below. Definitely not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally traced this down. My reducers were written correctly, but higher up the stack I was accidentally importing `combineReducers` from `redux-immer` instead of `redux` itself. `redux-immer` is a library for integrating immer into redux.

This resulted in running my store through immer twice (once via `createSlice` and once via `combineReducers`), which caused... unexpected... behaviors, including immer locking itself, resulting in the objects described above getting locked.

It's been a fun way to spend the last two weeks, for sure.